# CDE: multiple select

Tags: pentaho, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard that consist from two components: CCC Bar chart and Multiple select component.

I use the multiply select component for assignment param value, which is using in the datasource. (MDX query):

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[doc_count]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {[Dimension Usage date_publish.Hierarchy date_publish].[date_publish].Members} ON ROWS
    FROM [Docs]
    WHERE CrossJoin({${param_hosts}}, {[event].[active]})
```

So if I set (multiply select component) property `value array` with pairs:
 `( {arg:[host].[news.com] value:news.com}, {{arg:[host].[somesite.com] value:somesite.com}} )`, everything work perfect.
The parameter is bound to the component receives the correct value, for example: `[host]. [News.com], [host]. [Somesite.com]`.

But if I try to fill the multiply select component from the datasource it become unworkable.
As DataSource, I use the `sql over sqlJndi` with query: `SELECT distinct (host) as Id, concat ('[host]. [', Host, ']') as Value FROM docs_fact where dim_event_id = 1;`

The result this query is a table:

```
id              value
news.com     | [host].[news.com]
somesite.com | [host].[somesite.com]
```

Parameter is assigned a value: `news.com, somesite.com`

Changing the properties of the `Value as id` only affects which of the fields (id or value) will be shown to the user, and the parameter's value is not affected.

Tell me please, is it possible to specify which of the columns to be used for display to the user and which of the columns to be used to generate results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can change the dataset on the clientside using the postFetch function on the multi-select component.

```
function (dataset) {

    for (var i=0; i < dataset.resultset.length; i++) {
        var temp = dataset.resultset[i][0];
        dataset.resultset[i][0] = dataset.resultset[i][1];
        dataset.resultset[i][1] = temp;
    }

    return dataset; 
}
```

Or similar

Comment: Pedro Vale, could you give me an advice where i can find good tutorial or documentation about cde? every thing that i have found was only about  general things. and there is no inforamtion about details :(

Comment: We (webdetails) have both a CDE and a CDF tutorial for sale at www.webdetails.pt. There's also a very thorough CDE tutorial available at ambientbi.co.uk. Pentaho forums and the ##pentaho irc channel at irc.freenode.net are also good sources for information.